# 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?

Tags: symfony-2.3

When I run "php composer.phar update" command, I got
"'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file."

I have installed Git client and added PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you run "git" command in terminal, it works?
Maybe your PATH variable it's wrong.